# Connect jdbc to a server db

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**Localhost**

```
connection = DriverManager
    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skead","admin", "admin");
```

That is a way to access my localhost database.

But what if i want to access my **server database**(not localhost)?
How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just change `mysql://localhost:3306/skead` to `mysql://>YOUR SERVER IP HERE<:3306/skead` ?

Comment: I would like to see comments from downvoter. That will help question asker to see what he has done wrong

Comment: "*not localhost*" - well, replace `localhost` with the desired hostname...

Comment: @Nabin I downvoted due to lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2):

then you need to provide the **URL** as

```
jdbc:mysql://yourRemoteHost:portToWhichRemoteHostMysqlListens/remoteDBName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Server_Name/DBName","UserName", "Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://serverIPAddress:3307/db_name";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "redmouse";

//        String dbURLs = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name";
//        String usernames = "root";
//        String passwords = "redmouse";

      Connection dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
```